# The decision boundary found by your classifier?

Tags: graphing-functions, octave

Can someone please explain in terms of "How To" find the decision boundary found by your classifier? If I plot using Octave:

```
plot(theta);
```

I get nothing like I should see. If theta is:

```
theta = [-6, 1, 0];
```

I believe the answer should be:

[image]

Where the form is:

[image]

[image]

But I do not understand how and why. Please enlighten me!

**EDIT**
I am guessing, this graph is of the Sigmoid itself. The -6 is outright confusing.

Thank you Roland and Grand_chat for your help! I think I understand now! Thank you both!

Comment: What form does your classifier take, and what role does theta play in it? (Please update your question with that info.)

Comment: If this question is a question on octave, then stackoverflow might be better suited for this. If this is on the mathematical background what's meant by the classifyer theta, then this is the right place. In any case, you should add some context.

Comment: @grand_chat - Have added what I think is the form.

Comment: @Roland - I need to know the Math, understand how and why this is what it is. Also how I get the graph of this data like is shown.

Comment: Can you write out the equation of $g$? Is it  $g(t) = 1/(1+e^{-t})$? And do you classify "1" if $h_\theta(x) > 0.5$, and classify "0" otherwise?

Comment: What's $g$? A function like $\frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}$?

Comment: @grand_chat - these things are not clear to me. I believe g(z) and yes it seems to be the Sigmoid 1/(1 + e-t). Yes 1 >= 0.5 - But I have no values of x

Comment: Sorry, my Math is not the best. Takes a bit for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g(t) = 1/(1+e^{-t})$ and your classifier $h_\theta$ is designed to return one class if $h_\theta(x)>0.5$ and the other class if $h_\theta(x)<0.5$, then the decision boundary is the set of $x=(x_1,x_2)$ such that
$$
h_\theta(x) = 0.5\tag1
$$
By definition of $h_\theta$, (1) is equivalent to
$$
g(\theta_0+\theta_1x_1 +\theta_2 x_2) = 0.5\ .\tag2
$$
If you rearrange the equation 
$$
{1\over 1+e^{-z}} =: g(z) = 0.5
$$
to solve for $z$, you'll find that $z=0$. Therefore (2) is equivalent to
$$
\theta_0 + \theta_1x_1 + \theta_2x_2 = 0\tag3
$$
and (3) is the final form of your decision boundary. Plug in the given values of $(\theta_0,\theta_1,\theta_2)$ into (3) and you'll get the equation of a line:
$$
-6 + 1x_1 + 0x_2 = 0
$$
which simplifies to the line $$x_1 = 6\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g$ 'classifies' as $y=1$ when it's argument is $>0$ and $y = 1$ when it's argument is $<0$. (Most classifier functions work this way).

You have that the argument is $\theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1 + \theta_2x_2$ and we are asked which kind of classification results from the choice $\theta_0 = -6, \theta_1 = 1, \theta_2 = 0$.

The first thing to note is that $\theta_2 = 0$, which means that the argument reduces to $\theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1$, which is independet of $x_2$. This is what you see immediately in the picture: The classification boundary is independent of $x_2$, i.e. has the same value for every $x_2$ and is therefore parallel to the $x_2-$axis. Furthermore, we see that $\theta_0 = -6$, i.e. if $x_1= 6$, then $\theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1 = 0$, i.e. the decision boundary where the argument switches the sign is precisely the line $x_1 = 6$ (and $x_2$ being arbitrary).

Answer (score 0):

**Roland** and **grand_chat** both have correct answers. I see where I was going wrong. Probabitlity!

[image]

-6 becomes +6 by moving to the other side of the equation. X$1$ = 1 and X$2$ = 0 is the transition from 1 to 0.